# How to remove part of cube

Tags: modeling

[image]

How to remove the selected part of this mesh?

Comment: Could you not press X > Delete Faces?

Answer (score 1):

Edit mode, press <kbd>x</kbd> or menu Mesh then Delete-Faces

[image]